# Why isn't "getcontext().prec = 2" actually setting it so the use of Decimal() goes to two decimal places?

Tags: python, decimal

I am writing a program that deals with monetary values, as such I want it to output to two decimal places using decimal, unfortunately, this isn't working and it is outputting much longer numbers.

I've looked around online but so far it doesn't look like there are any answers for this specific issue, in case it was something happening in the rest of the program I ran a test piece of code using it just on a basic number and the same result occurred so it isn't the rest of my code. test below.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2
test = Decimal(5.859)
print(test)
```

I expected this to print the output of 5.86 or in the worst case at least 5.85 if it didn't round in the desired direction.

Instead, it printed.

```
5.8589999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375
```

the same output as though `getcontext().prec = 2` was never used

Please be aware moderately new to python so please don't just assume I'll know exactly what you mean if you throw random code at me without an explanation.

Comment: To begin with, passing a float object to the Decimal constructor **is not what you mean to be doing at all**. The whole *point* is that `float` objects are inherently imprecise.* so you are going to still have that imprecision if you pass a float to `Decimal`*. In any case, the precision you are worried about only comes into play during arithmetic operations. so see what happens when you do `test + Decimal('0.00001')`. then change the precision and try that again.

Comment: so, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial): "The significance of a new Decimal is determined solely by the number of digits input. Context precision and rounding only come into play during arithmetic operations." Which might be surprising.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Great explanations, although there's no need for `+Decimal('0.00001')`. A unary `+` operation (i.e. `+test`) would be enough.

Comment: @blhsing sure, but that may have been a bit cryptic, i think the above example is a bit more clear

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I personally find that adding an arbitrary non-zero number to the intended number to be more cryptic. I would simply make it `test + Decimal(0)` if one prefers to avoid using a unary operation.

Comment: @blhsing that seems reasonable

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the info, the information found online used some floats for their examples so I didn't think it would cause any issues. In the actual code I was using Decimal constructor on some floats in a list that had been passed through sum to get their total. The information found online led me to believe this would work.  I fixed my actual code by combining Decimal and round, it may not be the option in some situations but for my actual code it has done the job.

Comment: @Jay why don't you just use strings?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it wouldn't work for what I want the program to do, at least not to my knowledge, which I admit means there is more likely a way to make it work than not.

Comment: Well, look, to deal with monetary values accurately, you cannot use `float`. If you could expand on your constraints then perhaps someone could help you address this.

Answer (score 6):

As per [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) documentation, Context precision and rounding only come into play during arithmetic operations. So, in order to achieve your goal, you can do something like this:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 3
test = Decimal('5.859')/Decimal('1')
print(test)
```

output:

```
Decimal('5.86')
```

Comment: don't pass floats to the Decimal constructor!

Comment: There's also [`Context.create_decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.create_decimal).

Comment: Thanks, I found a work around in the mean time for the actual code itself.